# looking for a highlightFade plugin for mootools

Tags: mootools

Similar to the highlightFade jQuery plugin I was hoping to find something like this for mootools - anyone know if this exists?

Thank you

**Edit**

I was able to build my own for the time being

```
function highlightFadeOnSuccess(lnk) {
    var el = lnk.getParent().getParent().getChildren('td')[1];

    var morph = new Fx.Morph(el,{ 'duration':'300', link:'cancel',onComplete: function(){fadeOut(el);} });

    morph.start({ 'color':'rgb(255,255,0)' });
}

function fadeOut(el) {
    var morph = new Fx.Morph(el,{ 'duration':'300', link:'cancel'});
    morph.start({ 'color':'rgb(0,0,102)' });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you're not using [http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Tween#Element:highlight](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Tween#Element%3ahighlight)?

If you want to highlight it and then fade out, you could do:

```
var elem = $('element');

elem.addEvent('click',function(){
    this.highlight('#FF0000').get('tween').chain(function(){
        this.fade(0);    
    }.bind(this));
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/3KYqH/